# destroy alert by oncheck of another alert dialog box

Tags: javascript, php, html

i use all the alerts in javascript.i want to destroy all the dialog when user select on the check box of another alert prevventing dialog.
  for example some browser provide the dialog when we face some dialog repatedly one or more time and if we check  that check box after that that page do not show any dialog .
like chrom provide message like "Prevent this  page from creating additional dialog " which one check box option.
any one have solution for this thanks in advance and sorry for some gramer mistake

Comment: What does "destroy all the dialog" mean? You can't have more than one alert open on the same page at once.

Comment: i maean all the dialogs which are coded in same page like when i when checked for preventing dialog it shoud not show any alert or dialog after that.

Comment: may i use this code [MyWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.alert=null;"];         whith ajax calling from another page on onselected of dialog is it posible